# Error 3625: Group by and may not contain aggregate functions

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to do a calculation on a what-if basis, so I assumed I could've done this using the case when function. Such as:

```
SELECT                                                                                                          
TRIM(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM business_date))||'Q'||TRIM((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM business_date)+2)/3) as year_qtr,                 
case when orr_txt = '1' then  (sum(cast (rr9m as float)) / (sum(cast (total_observations as float)) - 0.5*sum(cast (lft as float)) )) end as  DR_1,
case when orr_txt = '2' then  (sum(cast (rr9m as float)) / (sum(cast (total_observations as float)) - 0.5*sum(cast (lft as float)) )) end as  DR_2,
case when orr_txt = '3' then  (sum(cast (rr9m as float)) / (sum(cast (total_observations as float)) - 0.5*sum(cast (lft as float)) )) end as  DR_3,
avg(cast (dp as float)) as Pred_PD                                  

FROM                                        
     raroc.pd_matrixRR a,                                       
     raroc.ccc_dp_sc  b,
     raroc.ratings_convert c                                        
WHERE                                                                                                   
     start_orr_code in (1)
     and case when a.scorecard_group = 'BB' then 'Business Banking' else a.scorecard_group end= b.rating_sys
     and a.orr_txt = b.bacrr
     and a.orr_txt = c.bacrr_text
     and orr_txt not in ('9-', '10', '11', '12', 'NR')                                      
     and rating_sys_grp = 'Scorecard'
     --and a.orr_txt = '1'
     --and scorecard_group = 'Large Corporation'
     --and scorecard_group = 'Large Corporation_FI'
     --and scorecard_group = 'Middle Market'
     --and scorecard_group = 'BB'
     --and scorecard_group = 'GCSBB'
     --and scorecard_group = 'Real Estate'
      and scorecard_group = 'Individuals'                                       
      and scorecard_group not like 'Sove%'                                      
      and scorecard_group not like 'Lega%'
      --and year_qtr < '2014Q2'                                                                                         
group by 1,2,3,4                            
ORDER BY 2,1
```

It apparently didn't compile and laughed at my logic. However, I'll get an error 3604 if I don't group it. The question is, how would I get about this in order to calculate the rate for category 1, 2, and 3.
Much appreciated!

SP

Comment: You should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the CASE inside the aggregate function like this:

```
       (sum(case when orr_txt = '1' then cast (rr9m as float) end)
     / (sum(case when orr_txt = '1' then cast (total_observations as float) end)
  - 0.5*sum(case when orr_txt = '1' then cast (lft end as float) end ) )) end as  DR_1,
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  The conditions go *inside* the aggregation functions.  I think this is the expression that you want (repeated 3 times of course for each value:

```
SELECT . . .
       (sum(case when orr_txt = '1' then cast(rr9m as float) end) /
        sum(case when orr_txt = '1' then cast(total_observations as float) end) -
        0.5 * sum(case when orr_txt = '1' then cast(lft as float) end)
       ) as DR_1, . . .
```

You can then change the `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY 1`.

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by

```
group by 
TRIM(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM business_date))||'Q'||TRIM((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM business_date)+2)/3)
, orr_txt
```